# Is oil-based house paint a health concern?

Tags: painting

Some use enamel to paint doors and windows. Some use enamel paint for few rooms. Some use enamel for entire house.

Reason: we can wash the doors/windows/walls if kids are scribbling on the walls or dusted

Using enamel paint for house is good or bad for health? Any idea.

Thanks.

Comment: Enamel is not a synonym for "oil based paint".  There are latex enamels.  Are you asking specifically about oil-based paints?

Comment: yes. oil based paints

Answer (score 2):

The type of enamel paint being used will be the key. Using an enamel with no VOCs (volatile organic compounds) is what you want to eliminate the health concerns. There are latex enamels that are washable and will provide the finish you want without the possible health concerns from outgassing VOCs.